# Creating numpy array from list gives wrong shape

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm creating several numpy arrays from a list of numpy arrays, like so:

```
seq_length = 1500
seq_diff = 200  # difference between start of two sequences
# x and y are 2D numpy arrays
x_seqs = [x[i:i+seq_length,:] for i in range(0, seq_diff*(len(x) // seq_diff), seq_diff)]
y_seqs = [y[i:i+seq_length,:] for i in range(0, seq_diff*(len(y) // seq_diff), seq_diff)]
boundary1 = int(0.7 * len(x_seqs))   # 70% is training set
boundary2 = int(0.85 * len(x_seqs))  # 15% validation, 15% test
x_train = np.array(x_seqs[:boundary1])
y_train = np.array(y_seqs[:boundary1])
x_valid = np.array(x_seqs[boundary1:boundary2])
y_valid = np.array(y_seqs[boundary1:boundary2])
x_test = np.array(x_seqs[boundary2:])
y_test = np.array(y_seqs[boundary2:])
```

I'd like to end up with 6 arrays of shape (n, 1500, 300) where n is either 70%, 15% or 15% of my data for the training, validation and test arrays, respectively.

This is where it goes wrong: the `_train` and `_valid` arrays turn out fine, but the `_test` arrays are one-dimensional arrays of arrays. That is:

- `x_train.shape` is `(459, 1500, 300)`
- `x_valid.shape` is `(99, 1500, 300)`
- `x_test.shape` is `(99,)`

But printing `x_test` verifies that it contains the correct elements - i.e. it's a 99-element long array of `(1500, 300)` arrays.

Why do the `_test` matrices get the wrong shape, while the `_train` and `_valid` matrices don't?

Answer (score 4):

The items in `x_seqs` vary in length.  When they are all the same length, `np.array` can make a 3d array from them; when they differ it makes an object array of lists.  Look at the `dtype` of `x_test`.  Look at the `[len(i) for i in x_test]`.

I took your code, added:

```
x=np.zeros((2000,10))
y=x.copy()
...
print([len(i) for i in x_seqs])
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_valid.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
```

and got:

```
1520:~/mypy$ python3 stack40643639.py 
[1500, 1500, 1500, 1400, 1200, 1000, 800, 600, 400, 200]
(7,)
(1, 600, 10)
(2,)
```