# Irregular Numpy matrix

Tags: numpy, matrix

In Numpy, it appears that the matrix can simply be a nested list of anything not limited to numbers. For example

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1,2,5],[3,'r']]
b = np.matrix(a)
```

generates no complaints.

What is the purpose of this tolerance when list can treat the object that is not a matrix in the strict mathematical sense?

Comment: It's because sometimes you want to store general objects (like strings or even more general-stuff). It's not just used for mathematical matrix-operations.

Comment: @sascha: My question is precisely that these situations can already by handled by list in the generic Python. Why do we need another a separate treatment in Numpy? I can see the purpose if, say, the matrix operation is extended to matrix of functions. But I do not think Numpy treats functions like that.

Comment: You can also use a list (list-of-lists) for matrix-multiplication, so why use numpy?

Comment: @sascha: A pre-written function, such as one in Numpy, modularizes a sequence of operations so that the sequence as a whole can be used repeatedly. It saves coding effort by compression. However, there is no such compression and effort saving here. Please elucidate it if you think otherwise.

Comment: Example: Mathematical-programming with Gurobi. Back in the days, maybe still today, there were only some dict-based constructs for storing all your variables for building up constraints (which i did not like). So i just took the variable-objects and put them into some numpy arrays which only work if a general object-type is supported (because a gurobi-variable is not a native python-type). So now i got a nice array / tensor of variables and can do all the crazy-indexing stuff and of course also np.dot(a,b) on my object-based numpy-data because these variable-objects overload + and co.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've created is an object dtype array:

```
In [302]: b=np.array([[1,2,5],[3,'r']])
In [303]: b
Out[303]: array([[1, 2, 5], [3, 'r']], dtype=object)
In [304]: b.shape
Out[304]: (2,)
In [305]: b[0]
Out[305]: [1, 2, 5]
In [306]: b[1]=None
In [307]: b
Out[307]: array([[1, 2, 5], None], dtype=object)
```

The elements of this array are pointers - pointers to objects else where in memory.  It has a data buffer just like other arrays.  In this case 2 pointers, 2

```
In [308]: b.__array_interface__
Out[308]: 
{'data': (169809984, False),
 'descr': [('', '|O')],
 'shape': (2,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '|O',
 'version': 3}
In [309]: b.nbytes
Out[309]: 8
In [310]: b.itemsize
Out[310]: 4
```

It is very much like a list - which also stores object pointers in a buffer. But it differs in that it doesn't have an `append` method, but does have all the array ones like `.reshape`.

And for many operations, `numpy` treats such an array like a list - iterating over the pointers, etc.  Many of the math operations that work with numeric values fail with object dtypes.

Why allow this?  Partly it's just a generalization, expanding the concept of element values/dtypes beyond the simple numeric and string ones.  `numpy` also allows compound dtypes (structured arrays). MATLAB expanded their matrix class to include `cells`, which are similar.

I see a lot of questions on SO about object arrays.  Sometimes they are produced in error, [Creating numpy array from list gives wrong shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643639/creating-numpy-array-from-list-gives-wrong-shape).

Sometimes they are created intentionally. `pandas` readily changes a data series to object dtype to accommodate a mix of values (string, nan, int).

`np.array()` tries to create as high a dimension array as it can, resorting to object dtype only when it can't, for example when the sublists differ in length.  In fact you have to resort to special construction methods to create an object array when the sublists are all the same.

This is still an object array, but the dimension is higher:

```
In [316]: np.array([[1,2,5],[3,'r',None]])
Out[316]: 
array([[1, 2, 5],
       [3, 'r', None]], dtype=object)
In [317]: _.shape
Out[317]: (2, 3)
```

Comment: Nice. Never saw that ```__array_interface__```. Also a good and clear explanation.