# Vectors and Cells/DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

In MATLAB, I could combine a column vector of numbers and string to a 3x1 Cell to produce a single cell (C) of 3x3 dimension as shown below

```
C = 

8   'CNDA-ESP_SIMRAD_MDS_DGPS_2000_2001.xlsx'   415x3 double

2   'CNDA-ESP_SIMRAD_MDS_DGPS_2006_2007.xlsx'   986x3 double

2   'CNDA-ESP_SIMRAD_MDS_DGPS_2010_2011.xlsx'   704x3 double
```

Is it possible to do this in Python?

Comment: You can use object dtype arrays.

Comment: How do i implement it @Divakar?

Comment: Initialize with `out = np.empty((3),dtype=object)` and start assigning each element one by one, where those elements would be `out[0] = [8   'CNDA-ESP_SIMRAD_MDS_DGPS_2000_2001.xlsx'   415x3 double]`, and so on.

Comment: @Divakar. You are the 21century avenger. I need to be in contact with you constantly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long before MATLAB had cells, Python had lists.  They are 1d, but can contain other lists.  In fact without `numpy` nested lists are used to create 'matrices'.

A `numpy` arrays with object dtype contain pointers to objects, so they are similar to lists.  You can't append to them as you can with lists.  But they are multidimensional like regular arrays.  So depending on your perspective they are enhanced lists or degraded ones.

Constructing a list is trival

```
alist = [array1, array2, array3, ...]
```

Constructing an object array can be trickier.  If the subarrays or objects differ in size and type, it is easy - just wrap the list version in `np.array(alist, dtype=object)`.

But if the subarrays all have the same shape, `np.array` creates a higher dimensional array from them.  The best way around that is to create 'blank' array of the right shape, and assign values.

I've discussed these issues at:

[Can I construct a numpy object zero-d array from its value in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711440/can-i-construct-a-numpy-object-zero-d-array-from-its-value-in-a-single-expressio)

There I mention `scipy.io.loadmat`, which is capable of loading MATLAB files.  You might try writing your cells to a .mat, and load them in Python.  That will give you ideas of how that function tries to create equivalents.

More on object arrays v lists at:
[Irregular Numpy matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40666695/irregular-numpy-matrix)